# move one block on another when hover

Tags: html, css

When I move mouse on red div I want grey div go a little upper. But when it moves and mouse happens to be on red div it starts to lag and hesitate between moving up and down. What should I do for this animation for avoiding this hesitation and moving grey object smooth?

```css
.dm-intro-news {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.dm-intro-news {
width: 390px;
height: 150px;
background: #333333;
transition: 0.4s;
}
.wr {display: inline-block;transition:2s}
.dm-short-news{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 390px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;

}
.dm-short-news:hover~.dm-intro-news{
  margin-top:-50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
    <div class="dm-short-news"></div>
    <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's easy, You just need remove `position:absolute` from `.dm-short-news:hover~.dm-intro-news`.

Let me know further clarification.

Hope it will help you. :)

```css
.dm-intro-news {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
transition: 0.5s;
position: relative;
}
.dm-intro-news {
width: 390px;
height: 150px;
background: #333333;
transition: 0.4s;
}
.wr {display: inline-block;transition:2s}
.dm-short-news{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 390px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;


}
.dm-short-news:hover~.dm-intro-news,
.dm-intro-news:hover{
  margin-top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
    <div class="dm-short-news"></div>
    <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I need this but grey div should be upper than red, fix it and I will tag it as an answer!

Comment: Yes, that is right what I wanted. Sry, could you help me with this again? I need to change scale of picture to 1.3 in the red div when I hover on it. How could I do it? You can use any picture, I just want to understand how could I realize it. I can ask another question about this topic if you want

Comment: You need to add 'transform: scale(1.3);' on hover. For more info, i have create new pen for you please review my code carefully. ->https://codepen.io/jaydeeep/pen/yLLmXeb

Answer (score 1):

This is because hover event will be cancelled when `.dm-intro-news` is on top.

Put `pointer-events: none;` on `.dm-intro-news`:

```css
.dm-intro-news {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: red;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.dm-intro-news {
width: 390px;
height: 150px;
background: #333333;
transition: 0.4s;
}
.wr {display: inline-block;transition:2s; position: relative;}
.dm-short-news{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 390px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;

}
.dm-short-news:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    }
.dm-short-news:hover~.dm-intro-news {
  margin-top:-50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
    <div class="dm-short-news"></div>
    <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but my grey div was falling down smoothly.. Now it is going down like this: upper part falls instaltly below, but its down part slides down, could you fix that thing?

Comment: Please check my edited answer. It's that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the position from your elements and consider hover on both elements:

```css
.wr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 390px;
}

.dm-short-news {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.dm-intro-news {
  height: 150px;
  background: #333333;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.dm-short-news:hover~.dm-intro-news,
.dm-intro-news:hover{
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news"></div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set an element to ignore the mouse cursor.

I added `pointer-events: none;` on `.dm-short-news`.

[edit] I also removed `position: absolute`.

```css
.dm-intro-news {
  position: relative;
  width: 390px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #333333;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dm-short-news{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 390px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}
.dm-short-news:hover~.dm-intro-news{
  margin-top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news"></div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```